# Android dir = rtl not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I am using the Robin Herbots input mask for a time input (i.e. 1:23:45). I have it set up so that the html input box is dir = "rtl".

When I enter in "12345" on anything but an Android it populates "1:23:45" but when I put it in on an Android it populates as "5:43:21". So technically it is going from right to left but I want the first number to move to the left as I type in more numbers, i.e. typing in "123" I want to result in "1:23" rather than "3:21". It looks like it's just the fact that the cursor is not remaining at the end of the input but I can't seem to fix it.

Here is the jQuery I am using :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#result").inputmask("9:99:99",{numericInput:true, placeholder:"0"});
```

Can someone please provide direction? Thanks!